# Need help optimizing runtime on a problem

Tags: algorithm, optimization, runtime

> I have two types of operations possible:
>
> [0,a,b] - Create and save a rectangle of size axb
>
> [1,a,b] - check whether every PREVIOUS saved rectangle can be fit inside this rectangle of axb. You can rotate rectangles by 90 degrees. We try to fit each rectangle one at a time and not together.
> I need to return an array of booleans representing answers to second operation in the order in which they appear.
> eg.
> operations = [1,1,1]
> output = [true]
> No rectangles saved so they can fit inside anything.
>
> ex.
> operations = [[0,1,3], [0,4,2], [1,3,4], [1,3,2]]
> output = [true,false]
> [1,3] and 4,2 can fit inside [3,4] so true
> [1,3] can fit but [4,2] cannot fit inside [3,2] so false.
>
> I've tried the brute force solution of rotating each previous rectangle and checking if it fits and it is too slow
> What's the faster solution?

Comment: Is there some likely maximum number of previously saved rectangles? What would be a normal number of saved rectangles?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a true/false for every saved rectangle, in the order they were saved, then at some point you have to check every saved rectangle.

To speed things up, when you save a rectangle, also save its area and its longer dimension.

At test time, if the area of a saved rectangle is greater than the area of the test rectangle, then it cannot fit. This is only one test instead of two. If the area is less than or equal then the longer dimension of the saved rectangle must be less than or equal to the longer dimension of the test rectangle. So somtimes you will stiil have to do two tests.

You will gain some speed at test time for a very small loss of speed at save time.

Answer (score 0):

**Brute Force Solution:**

**Approach:**

- For each operation:

  - If the operation is 0, save the rectangle's dimensions as a pair.
  - If the operation is 1, traverse the saved rectangles and check if each rectangle can be placed in the current box while considering rotations.

**Time Complexity:** O(n + m*o) where n is the total number of operations, m is the number of saved rectangles and o is number of times "1" operation occurs

**Auxiliary Space:** O(m) where m is the number of saved rectangles.

**Optimized Solution:**

**Approach:** The idea is to maintain a virtual smallest box that can contain every saved rectangle.

- For each operation:

  - If the operation is 0, get the rectangle's maximum and minimum dimensions (a,b):

    - `currMaxDimension = max(a, b)` and `currMinDimension = min(a, b).`
  - Compare the dimensions with our virtual box, updating virtualMaxDimension and virtualMinDimension as follows:

    - `virtualMaxDimension = max(virtualMaxDimension, currMaxDimension)`
    - `virtualMinDimension = max(virtualMinDimension, currMinDimension)`
  - If the operation is 1, compare if your virtual box can fit into the current box.

    - If it can, then every saved rectangle can fit inside; otherwise, they won't fit.

**Time Complexity:** O(n)

**Auxiliary Space:** O(1)

This optimized solution reduces the time complexity by efficiently tracking the dimensions of the virtual box, resulting in a more efficient algorithm for solving the problem.